# Why the DataFrame.nlargest does not order a result?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example from Pandas documentation v0.22.0:

```
In [330]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-2, -1, 1, 10, 8, 11, -1],
                             'b': list('abdceff'),
                             'c': [1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.2, np.nan, 3.0, 4.0]})

In [332]: df.nlargest(5, ['a', 'c'])
Out[332]: 
     a  b    c
 6  -1  f  4.0
 5  11  f  3.0
 3  10  c  3.2
 4   8  e  NaN
 2   1  d  4.0
```

Why the result is not ordered first by 'a' and then by 'c'?

At the same time the applying `nlargest()` with single column always order the result:

```
df.nlargest(5,['a'])
Out[110]: 
     a  b    c
5  11.0  f  3.0
3  10.0  c  3.2
4   8.0  e  NaN
2   1.0  d  4.0
1  -1.0  b  2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a not bug, but expected, check [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19563#issuecomment-363776062):

> **nlargest** doesn't sort the values (which is part of why it's faster).
>
> You can sort afterwards.

```
In [32]: df.sort_values(['a', 'c'], ascending=False).head(5)
Out[32]:
    a  b    c
5  11  f  3.0
3  10  c  3.2
4   8  e  NaN
2   1  d  4.0
6  -1  f  4.0

In [33]: df.nlargest(5, ['a', 'c']).sort_values(['a', 'c'], ascending=False)
Out[33]:
    a  b    c
5  11  f  3.0
3  10  c  3.2
4   8  e  NaN
2   1  d  4.0
6  -1  f  4.0
```